# neo4j order by on relationship not looking at index

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have been looking into this problem for while now. I have neo4j setup with the following schema :

User has friends and User likes movie. One of my primary usecases is to get all the movies liked by all my friends. This is how I am doing it:

```
start user=node:userIndex(uid="1234") 
   match user-[friend_rela:FRIENDS]-(friend)-[movie_rela:LIKE]->movie 
   return distinct movie,movie_rela,friend 
   order by movie_rela.timeStamp desc 
   skip 0 
   limit 5;
```

It works allright, but the time taken by the query is in the order of ~10seconds. If I remove the 'order by movie_rela.timeStamp desc' it comes back in around 2 seconds. I have indexed the timestamp property in the relationship. I then read that **Neo4J does not honor indexes on an Order by clause**. Is there some way I can fix this ? The above query is one of my primary usecases.

Thanks.

Comment: hey did you try out anything??

Comment: I kept my schema as it is Sumeet, for now. When I directly query the db, things seem to be super fast. But when I use SDN to do the job, something goes wrong. Still looking into why. Thanks for everything anyways Sumeet. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can redesign your graph. Like eg. suppose a friend can like multiple movies and different timestamps. So your graph can be

```
(u:User)-[:FRIENDS]->(friend:User)-[r1:Like]->(m1:Movie)-[r2:Like]->(m2:Movie)-...
```

Where the relationship `Like` is created from User in an order from latest to oldest. And r1,r2 will contain the timestamp as well as userid to uniquely form the path from a particular user to a movie in the entire chain. The Movie connected to User directly is the latest and as the distance (the number of Like relationship) increases between the User Node and the mOvie node, that particular movie is watched oldest.(you can reverse the order as per your convenience)

The benefit of having such design will be that there would be no requirement of ordering based on timestamp.

For any user if you wish to get all the movies he liked then just run

```
Match (u:User)-[:Like*1..]->(m:Movie) return m
```

here m will be returned in order of the kind of design you chose ie either ascending order or descending order of the movie watched timestamp.

Comment: I am using SDN for my neo4j project. The relationship property clearly defines a start node type and an end node type. From the above example, the same relationship has a start node of 'User' or 'Movie'. I like the idea, but contemplating on how it can be done. Also I use Neo4j 1.9.5. Isnt [:Like*1..] in Neo4j 2.0 ?

Comment: No.. you can do that kind of match in neo4j 1.9

Comment: ok.. What about creating a relationship using SDN with different type of start nodes ? Because in this case, the LIKE relationship would have user and movie as the start node.

Comment: also, a user can have many friends and each friend could have his own set of movies. Given the above method, how can I aggregate all the movies liked by his friends, ordering by timestamp ? I could still get a list of all the movies all his friends like, but then comes the ordering, wouldnt it still be a problem ?

Comment: you can have the attribute userid in the relationship Like along with timestamp.. so for a particular user and all the movies he liked will have those userid to identify his unique likes. The list of movie nodes returned will be in order as the nodes are stored in the form of a linkedlist in the underlying structure.

Comment: a friend is basically a user.. and a :Friend relation exists only between user to user.. so treating a friend as a user and designing each user's branch of all the movies he likes arranging them in the order of when he watched them is the basic idea...

Comment: regarding SDN,  i havent actually used the ORM that Sprign provides for creating relationships.. in my projects i prefer creating relationships via executing Cypher queries from java.. its much faser.. but still i think you can do it with sdn too.. its just a matter of creating relationship between two nodes..

Comment: Hi Sumeet. I get the idea and I think its a great way of modeling the graph. I still have one burning question though : Assuming the graph is modeled in the way you mentioned, what is the query Ill use to get all the movies liked by all your friends, ordered by timeStamp ? This still requires you to merge the list of all movies by all your friends in timeStamp order. Am I right ? Is there a query which would do this without order by ? Thanks for your time Sumeet.

Comment: yes it wouldnt require order by. The nodes will be returned in a sorted fashion.. the query will be like

Match (u:user) -[:friend]->(f:friend)-[r:likes*]->(m:movie) where u.userId= 1 and u <> f and all(t in r where t.userId = u.userId) return u,f,collect(m) as movies